# GWT History - Why does it change the focus of my screen?

Tags: java, gwt, browser-history, gwt-history

I have a simple application structure that will contain three composites at any one time - my header, footer and content composites. The composites are laid out in the follow manner.

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
    <div id="content">
    <div id="footer">
</body>
```

The composites are assigned to the three `<div>`'s in my `EntryPoint`. The `EntryPoint` also contains a History Handler as follows.

```
History.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
        String historyToken = event.getValue();

        if(historyToken.isEmpty()) {
            parseTokens();
            ContentContainer.INSTANCE.setContent(new IndexScreen());
        }

        else if(historyToken.equalsIgnoreCase("registration")) {
            ContentContainer.INSTANCE.setContent(new RegisterScreen());
        }

        else if(historyToken.equalsIgnoreCase("login")) {
            ContentContainer.INSTANCE.setContent(new LoginScreen());
        }
    }
});

History.fireCurrentHistoryState();
```

In my Composites, I have several `ClickEvent` handlers that look similar to the following.

```
@UiHandler("registerLink")
public void handleClick(ClickEvent event) {
    ContentContainer.INSTANCE.setContent(new RegisterScreen());
    History.newItem("registration", true);
}
```

This registers the history very nicely. It also brings me to the appropriate pages when I click the back button. However, it has the very odd effect of focusing the browser on the content composite, with the effect of the browser being scrolled to the bottom. It's not a deal breaker but it kind of breaks the user experience a little. *(Do let me know if the explanation isn't clear, I'll add images)*

What exactly is causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

GWT history tokens work with the hash `#` token. In html this was originally intended to use the browser to focus on a specific part of the page, if an element has a `name` or `id` with the string after the `#` token. Could it be you have an `id` matching your history token?

Also in you `handleClick` you call `setContent`. But if I'm correct the call after it triggers a change event and will end up in the `onValueChange`, which also calls the `setContent`. So it looks like you are calling `setContent` twice here.

Comment: Good spot on the `setContent`. I have removed the duplicate code. However, I do not have any elements whose name matches by history token. Puzzling...